# Truncate word that comes before hyphen in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am curious as to how I could truncate the word that comes before the hyphen in a word, for example:

```
[Jazz] - The 1970's Blues
```

would become...

```
The 1970's Blues
```

I know how to do this in PHP and that there are many functions that make this possible in PHP... I am just curious as to how this could work with jQuery!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following:

```
var text="[Jazz] - The 1970's Blues";
alert(text.substring(text.indexOf("-")+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var msg="[Jazz] - The 1970's Blues";

msg=msg.split("-")[1];

console.log(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML Code:**

```
<p>[Jazz] - The 1970's Blues</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        alert($(this).text().split('-')[1]); //The 1970's Blues
    });
});
```